# What regexp to use for removing addresses from emailaddresses using GAS

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I can't get the regExp syntax into my head, so if would like to ask a simple question here.

I have emailaddresses

**name1 < somename1@domain1.com>, name2 < somename2@domain2.com>**

I would like to keep **name1, name2**  but remove the rest

What expression to use?

Basically I want to use a RegExp for

```
 while (to != '')
 {
    var indexOne = to.indexOf('<');
    var indexTwo = to.indexOf('>');
    if ((indexOne > 0) && (indexTwo > indexOne))
    {
       to = to.substr(0, indexOne - 1) + to.substr(indexTwo, to.length - indexTwo - 1);
    }
    else break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
var s = "name1 < somename1@domain1.com>, name2 < somename2@domain2.com>, name3 < somename3@domain3.com>";
var p = /\s?<(.*?)>/g
console.log(s.replace(p, '')); // name1, name2, name3
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nanapoha/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Thanks!   some do know, and some will never learn..... I guess I belong to the second category....

Comment: @SoftwareTester I think Regex is something that is easily forgotten :)

Comment: @hex494D49
Look at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) it is enormously helpful and lets you search through a (condensed) manual for common syntax. I can't recommend it enough